# Why is the compiler saying a return value is borrowed?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a function that as far as I understand isn't borrowing anything from it's input parameters and so I am not fully sure why I get a complaint about lifetimes. I am just using Sender from `std::sync::mpsc` and the lifeguard crate to provide `Recycled`.

My main question is how do I fix this, but secondly why does the compiler think I'm returning a borrowed value?

```rust
fn spawn_encoders(config: &Config, sender: Sender<Recycled<Vec<u8>>>) -> Vec<Sender<Recycled<Vec<u8>>>> {
    let mut senders = Vec::with_capacity(1 as usize);

    // removed other code

    senders
}
```

```
77 | fn spawn_encoders(config: &Config, sender: Sender<Recycled<Vec<u8>>>) -> Vec<Sender<Recycled<Vec<u8>>>> {
   |                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from `config` or `sender`
```

Comment: [`Recycled<'a, T>`](https://zslayton.github.io/lifeguard/lifeguard/struct.Recycled.html) does have a lifetime parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Recycled` struct contains a borrow. You're also taking a reference to a Config. The compiler doesn't know whether the return value will live as long as the `&Config`, or as long as the borrow inside of the `Recycled`. You need to give an explicit lifetime parameter to the return value. In this case, you use a generically declared `'a` to indicate that the return value lives as long as the `Sender`:

```
fn spawn_encoders<'a>(config: &Config, sender: Sender<Recycled<'a, Vec<u8>>>) -> Vec<Sender<Recycled<'a, Vec<u8>>>> {
    let mut senders = Vec::with_capacity(1 as usize);

    // removed other code

    senders
}
```